# Click event of input element is not fired on http.post success

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

html:

```
<input type="file" id="mypic" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)" />
<div style="float:right;">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="yesClick('/paLabel/mainLabel=')">yes</button>
</div>
```

angular:

```
$scope.yesClick = function (viewName) {
    var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
    $log.log("input: " + input);
    input.click();

    $log.log(viewName);
    $location.path(viewName);
}
```

The example above works fine and the click-event of the input element is raised.
But when I try the same in a http.post-success function it fails!?

```
$scope.yesClick = function (viewName) {
    CheckAmount($scope.amount, viewName);
}

function CheckAmount(val,viewName) {

    var endpoint = Model.getServerAdress() + "CheckAmount";
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: endpoint,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        data: 'amount=' + $scope.amount
    };

    $http(req)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.amountDB = makeJsonString(data, $log);

            if ($scope.amountDB == val)
            {
                var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
                $log.log("input: " + input);
                input.click();

                $location.path(viewName);
            }
            else {
                ...
            }

        })
        .error(function (data) {
            $log.log("ERROR" + data);
        });
}
```

In this case the click-event is not fired!
What is the problem? In both cases the log shows me that the input-object created by `document.querySelector` is a `HTMLInputElement`.

Comment: What does the console show when you click it?

Comment: input: [object HTMLInputElement] - the http.post method return with succss, but the event is not fired...

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your html-object into an jQuery-object: `$(input).click();`, dunno if i get this right, just a gues into the blue

Comment: i tried "var myElement = document.getElementById("mypic");      angular.element(myElement).triggerHandler("click");" without success. Till now I have no jQuery lib referenced in my Project, I thought I can manage verything with angularJS...

Comment: **Rather the question is**: why does it work directly in the button event, but NOT in the sucess function ...?!? Different scopes?

Comment: really nobody any idea....?